# How to crawl using wget to download ONLY HTML files (ignore images, css, js)

Tags: wget, web-crawler

Essentially, I want to crawl an entire site with Wget, but I need it to NEVER download other assets (e.g. imagery, CSS, JS, etc.).  I only want the HTML files.

[Google searches](https://www.google.com/search?q=wget%20crawl%20no%20assets&oq=wget%20crawl%20no%20images) are completely useless.

Here's a command I've tried:

```
wget --limit-rate=200k --no-clobber --convert-links --random-wait -r -E -e robots=off -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36" -A html --domain=www.example.com http://www.example.com
```

Our site is hybrid flat-PHP and CMS. So, HTML "files" could be `/path/to/page`, `/path/to/page/`, `/path/to/page.php`, or `/path/to/page.html`.

I've even included `-R js,css` but it still downloads the files, THEN rejects them (pointless waste of bandwidth, CPU, and server load!).

Comment: what's the command you've tried so far?  If the naming of files is consistent, you should be able to use the -R flag.  Alternatively, you could use the --ignore-tags flag and ignore script and img tags.

Comment: Opposite: [Exclude list of specific files in wget](http://superuser.com/questions/487198/exclude-list-of-specific-files-in-wget)

Comment: I've tried using --accept=html, but it downloads CSS files THEN deletes them. I want to prevent them from ever downloading. A headers request is fine, though -- E.g. I notice `Length: 558 [text/css]` on the files I don't want. If I could stop the request if the header doesn't return `text/html`, I'd be elated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

@ernie's comment about `--ignore-tags` lead me down the right path!
When I looked up `--ignore-tags` in `man`, I noticed `--follow-tags`.

Setting `--follow-tags=a` allowed me to skip `img`, `link`, `script`, etc.

It's probably too limited for some people looking for the same answer, but it actually works well in my case (it's okay if I miss a couple pages).

If anyone finds a way to allow for scanning ALL tags, but prevents `wget` from rejecting files only after they're downloaded (they should reject based on filename or header Content-type before downloading), I will very happily accept their answer!

Comment: `--follow-tags=a` might not be strict enough because it will still permit downloading other file types (e.g., images) if they are linked in `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 13):

what about adding the options:

```
--reject '*.js,*.css,*.ico,*.txt,*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.mp3,*.pdf,*.tgz,*.flv,*.avi,*.mpeg,*.iso'
--ignore-tags=img,link,script 
--header="Accept: text/html"
```

Comment: I like to use both `--follow-tags=a` with `--reject`.